# Azure DevOps API access without a user

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

Is it possible to pull work items from the DevOps API without needing a user to be logged in to get an access token every time?

I am trying to create a back-end service that pulls work items from the API every so often to generate a report. Can I just generate a one-time access key to use with that back-end service?

I've looked around the documentation, but it seemed like it all requires either a PAT or Azure Active Directory authorization/authentication.

**Here's the docs for the API**: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/backlogs/get%20backlog%20level%20work%20items?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

Comment: I know that a PAT will expire eventually, but why don't you consider that to be a "one-time access key"?

Comment: @Crowcoder yeah I guess my wording was off. A PAT is a one-time access key, but I need something that won't expire so I don't have to keep generating a new one. I don't believe there is a way to do that programmatically without some sort of user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/manage-authorizations?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops
and
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops

Basically authorize applications to use devops based on your credentials using oauth. similar to an app registration.

Thats the only way I can see without PAT and manual login each time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your personal account, you could create a fake AAD user then add it to your Azure DevOps Service.

Use that account to create a Personal Access Token. Similar to Build Service account to pull source code/work items. This should be a easy way to track everything.

But the limitation here is also obvious: this needs involvement of IT department, and also causes additional costs, since every user is billed.

---

Allow personal access tokens that do not expire is **not supported** right now. There is a related [user voice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/817953/allow-personal-access-tokens-that-do-not-expire.html).

As an alternatively way you could use OAuth just as alphaz18 suggested. Details please refer-- [Authorize access to REST APIs with OAuth 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops)